# What is the Path.get(".") refering to in my Java project?

Tags: java

In my current project the root directory is `C:\Users\Duke`. The Java class which calls `Path.get(".")` is in the path of `C:\Users\Duke\src\dependencies\storage\Store.java`. I needed to write and save data to a file, but since it has to run on different systems, I could not specify the absolute path.

I did a call on `Path.get(".").forEach(System.out::println)` and it printed out all the directories in `src` instead of `storage`. This has left me extremely confused. Shouldn't the `Path.get(".")` refer to current directory of where the code resides, which is in the `storage` directory?

Comment: The root directory of the sources is - in fact - `src`.

Comment: But when I run `println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` it returns `\Users\Duke`

Comment: The `user.dir` system property is not related to the working directory the program is run from.

Answer (score 2):

A `.` denotes a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) to the ["working directory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), namely the directory your program is run from. This is typically *not* the directory or path of the source file(s) your program is compiled from. You can do `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()` to see the exact directory it represents.

If you're using an IDE it can be hard to tell which directory it uses as its working directory, but typically it will be the project root. You can usually configure the working directory from within the IDE.

If you're trying to load files, such as data files, that are part of the project you may find [resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) better than accessing the filesystem directly.

Comment: Will the working directory or the project structure of the directory change if someone else where to run it from let's say linux or macOS as opposed to Windows.

Comment: @KenGondor it has nothing to do with project structure. It's typically the directory from which the `java` command was invoked.

Comment: @KenGondor It isn't related to the project structure, just how the program runs. When a program is run it is associated with a "working directory" that determines how relative paths (like `.`) are resolved. This is useful so that you don't have to hard-code absolute paths into your program. For example (on unix) `mv foo.txt bar.txt` renames a `foo.txt` in the "current working directory". If you had to write out the full absolute path every time that would be inconvenient and brittle. `Files.move(Paths.get("foo.txt"), Paths.get("bar.txt"))` works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`.` returns the application's working directory. In general that's the directory from where you are starting the Java Virtual Machine in order to execute Java classes.

It can't refer to the location of the code because that can be everywhere, e.g. some place in the internet where your classloader downloaded the classes that are executed (something that was very common in the Old Days[TM] when Java Applets were still a thing or with Webstart-applications).